# What is the proper way to call a function (from functions.php) on a link click?

Tags: php, functions, permalinks, links, callbacks

When using frameworks, we have routes where we can configure a callback functions for links, in drupal too there are menus that can be used to do the same.
So i would like to know if there is a proper way in Wordpress to "do something" like call a function from functions.php when some link is clicked.

Comment: Depends on what you need to do I guess. Simplest version (that’s conceptually related to what you’re describing) is to create a rewrite rule (with `add_rewrite_rule()`) to set ‘query variables’ based on the URL. Then hook into various places to act on these variables. Such as `template_redirect` to redirect, `template_include` to render a custom template or just `init` to run arbitrary code. There’s other simpler options for certain functionality you might want, but it really depends on what you want to do. A specific use case might result in more useful answers.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thank you for your answer.
Here is what i need to do: I have a custom post type (invoice), and i would like to call a function that will generate it as pdf, from a link that will be on single-invoice.php template.